# What would Maxwell's equations look like in a universe which followed Galilean transformations?

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations, galilean-relativity

I was wondering how the electromagnetic force would behave in a Gallilean transformation universe. Would the magnetic force be non-existent?

We know that Gallilean transformations are Lorentz transformations as $c\rightarrow \infty$. How does taking this limit affect the behavior of the electromagnetic force (i.e. Maxwell's equations)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galilean_electromagnetism

Comment: @G.Smith wow, I had no idea such a thing existed!